# mask AP とbox APはそれぞれどうやって計算するのでしょうか。

Tags: 機械学習, 画像

画像認識タスクの一つであるinstance segmentationにおいて、論文中にmask AP、box APという指標が登場しますがどうやって計算するのか定義が見つかりません（日本語、英語ともに）。

ご存知の方教えていただけますか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: どの論文なのかリンクを貼ってください。

Answer (score 0):

以下のコードの"segm"パラメータを指定した場合がmaskで、"bbox"を指定した場合がboxかと。
https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/8c9bcc3cf640524c4c20a9c40e89cb6a2f2fa0e9/PythonAPI/pycocotools/cocoeval.py#L29

segmがmaskと関係するのは以下のコメントからです。
https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/8c9bcc3cf640524c4c20a9c40e89cb6a2f2fa0e9/PythonAPI/pycocotools/cocoeval.py#L102

なお"AP"とはaverage precisionのことです。
https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/8c9bcc3cf640524c4c20a9c40e89cb6a2f2fa0e9/PythonAPI/pycocotools/cocoeval.py#L430